# Get the position of a GUI.Button and instantiate in its position

Tags: unity, gui

I am trying to instantiate a GUI.Box in the position of my GUI.Button when it is clicked but I just cant seem to get the position of the button. The button does change position.

Here is the code of my button in my Editor script:

```
void OnGUI () {
     GUI.Button(new Rect (5,95, 300, 100), "Hello");
}
```

Comment: I'd like to first point out that OnGUI is on it's way out and is no longer recommended from Unity. Secondly, you could store the rect in a private, class variable. Then you have a global reference to it and can swap a box there instead. I'm not 100 percent that's what you are trying to do so I won't make this an actual answer.